# How to display the value of a formula in the previous record in the new record crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, report, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

hi i want to show value of the previous record in new record

```
g1 =     if {Mah.Mahf1} <> "" then (tonumber({Mah.Mahg1})/1000  ) * tonumber({Mah.Mahf1})
```

...

```
g2 =     if {Mah.Mahf2} <> "" then (tonumber({Mah.Mahg2})/1000  ) * tonumber({Mah.Mahf2})
```

to g30

{Mah.Mahf1} is price

{Mah.Mahg1} is Weight

{Mah.Mah1} is name of the material

{Mah.MahName} is name of product

```
 end price =  tonumber({@g1})+tonumber({@g2})+tonumber({@g3})+tonumber({@g4})+tonumber({@g5})+tonumber({@g6})+tonumber({@g7})+tonumber({@g8})+tonumber({@g9})
+tonumber({@g10})+tonumber({@g11})+tonumber({@g12})+tonumber({@g13})+tonumber({@g14})+tonumber({@g15})+tonumber({@g16})+tonumber({@g17})+tonumber({@g18})+tonumber({@g19})+tonumber({@g20})+tonumber({@g21})+tonumber({@g22})
+tonumber({@g23})+tonumber({@g24})+tonumber({@g25})+tonumber({@g26})+tonumber({@g27})+tonumber({@g28})+tonumber({@g29})+tonumber({@g30})
```

[image]
Sometime there are several products

like the Picture below

[image]

record 8 "gg" consisting of records 3 and 5 and must show "412,585" but show nothing

What should i do?

it's important please help!

Comment: Shojaeensab - What do you mean by show value of the previous record in new record. When the Current cell value is empty do you Need to display the previous cell value ? Why the combination of 3 & 5 should show in 8. As I don't see any relation or relevant information.

Comment: @Roshan forget all . how to show  filed {endprice} in endprice  from previous record  
when mah.name = mah.mah1